# Moose structured types

Tags: perl, moose

I'd like to create a structured type in Moose that can be used as the type for another Moose attribute.  For example, I'd like to be able to create a `name` attribute which has its own `value` and `error` attributes.

I would therefore like to know the best way of achieving this.  I have created a working example by defining a simple Moose class to represent a generic `Field` object.  This has the `value` and `error` attributes.  I have then created another Moose class for the `Person` object. This has `id` and `name` attributes, both of which are of type `Field`:

Define a generic field object:

```
package MyApp::Type::Field;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

has 'value' => ( is => 'rw' );  
has 'error' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Str' );

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Define a Person object which uses the field object:

```
package MyApp::Person;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MyApp::Type::Field;

has 'id'   => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'MyApp::Type::Field' );    
has 'name' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'MyApp::Type::Field' );

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Do something with the Person object:

```
package MyApp::Test;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MyApp::Person;

my $person = MyApp::Person->new();

# This works.
$person->id( MyApp::Type::Field->new() );
$person->id->value( 1 );
$person->id->error( 'Not found' );

# This fails as the name object has not yet been defined.
$person->name->value( 'Dave' );
# Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at ...

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

This works, but in `MyApp::Test` I would like to be able to directly access the `value` and `error` attributes of the person's `name` and `id` without first having to instantiate a new `MyApp::Type::Field` object for each of the person's attributes.

Or, to put it another way, I'd prefer it if the user of the `Person` class did not have to do this: `$person->id( MyApp::Type::Field->new() );` before being able to use the `id` attribute.

Is there a nice clean way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn’t you simply supply a `default` for the properties?

```
has 'id' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'MyApp::Type::Field',
    default => sub { MyApp::Type::Field->new }
);
```

…or do the equivalent in `BUILD`.

Comment: Ah yes, all of a sudden it seems so obvious.  :-)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You also might try coercion:

```
coerce 'MyApp::Type::Field'
    => from 'Int'
    => via  { MyApp::Type::Field->new( value => shift ) }
    ;
```

That way it's only:

```
$person->id( 1 );
```

to set it. Although setting the error would still need to go the way you have it.

---

I probably should have mentioned that you need to do the following:

- Add `Moose::Util::TypeConstraints` to the package where you put the `coerce`.
- Add the `coerce` flag to the field:

  ```
  has id => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'MyApp::Type::Field', coerce => 1 );
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd actually already added coercion from both Str and HashRef, which has enabled me to create a new Person like this: `$person = MyApp::Person->new( id => { value => 1, error => 'Not found' }, name => { value => 'Dave' } );`