# Moose coercion and builders

Tags: perl, attributes, moose, coercion

This follows on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324465/moose-structured-types) about Moose structured types.  I apologise for the length of the question.  I wanted to ensure that I included all the necessary details.

`MyApp::Type::Field` defines a structured type.  I use coercion to allow its `value` attribute to be set more easily from my `Person` class (see example below).  Note that in my real application, where the Field type is used for more than just a person's name, I also coerce from a HashRef.

I also need to set the `MyApp::Type::Field` `size` and `required` read-only attributes from `MyApp::Person` at build time.  I can do this using a builder method, but this is not called if coercion is used, as my coercion creates a new object directly, without using the builder method.

I can get round this by adding an `around` method modifier to `MyApp::Person` (see example below), but this feels messy.  The `around` method modifier is called frequently, but I only need to set the read-only attributes once.

Is there a better way to do this, whilst still allowing coercion?  The `MyApp::Type::Field` class cannot initialize `size` and `required` via defaults or builders, as it has no way of knowing what the values should be.

It may simply be the case that I forgo coercion in favour of having no `around` modifier.

**`MyApp::Type::Field`**

```
coerce 'MyApp::Type::Field'
    => from 'Str'
        => via { MyApp::Type::Field->new( value => $_ ) };

has 'value'    => ( is => 'rw' );
has 'size'     => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Int',  writer => '_set_size',     predicate => 'has_size' );
has 'required' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Bool', writer => '_set_required', predicate => 'has_required' );
```

**`MyApp::Person`**

```
has name => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'MyApp::Type::Field', lazy => 1, builder => '_build_name', coerce  => 1 );       

sub _build_name {
    print "Building name\n";
    return MyApp::Type::Field->new( size => 255, required => 1 );
}
```

**`MyApp::Test`**

```
print "Create new person with coercion\n";
my $person = MyApp::Person->new();
print "Set name\n";
$person->name( 'Joe Bloggs' );
print "Name set\n";
printf ( "Name: %s [%d][%d]\n\n", $person->name->value, $person->name->size, $person->name->required );

print "Create new person without coercion\n";
$person = MyApp::Person->new();
print "Set name\n";
$person->name->value( 'Joe Bloggs' );
print "Name set\n";
printf ( "Name: %s [%d][%d]\n\n", $person->name->value, $person->name->size, $person->name->required );
```

Prints:

```
Create new person with coercion
Set name
Name set
Name: Joe Bloggs [0][0]

Create new person without coercion
Set name
Building name
Name set
Name: Joe Bloggs [255][2]
```

Add an `around` method modifier to `MyApp::Person`, and change the builder so that it doesn't set `size` and `required`:

```
around 'name' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    print "Around name\n";

    unless ( $self->$orig->has_size ) {
        print "Setting size\n";
        $self->$orig->_set_size( 255 );
    };

    unless ( $self->$orig->has_required ) {
        print "Setting required\n";
        $self->$orig->_set_required( 1 );
    };

    $self->$orig( @_ );
};

sub _build_name {
    print "Building name\n";
    return MyApp::Type::Field->new();
}
```

When `MyApp::Test` is run, `size` and `required` are set twice.

```
Create new person with coercion
Set name
Around name
Building name
Setting size
Setting required
Name set
Around name
Setting size
Setting required
Around name
Around name
Name: Joe Bloggs [255][3]

Create new person without coercion
Set name
Around name
Building name
Name set
Around name
Around name
Around name
Name: Joe Bloggs [255][4]
```

**Proposed solution**

[daotoad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59135/daotoad) suggestion of creating a subtype for each `MyApp::Person` attribute, and coercing that subtype from a `Str` into a `MyApp::Type::Field` works quite well.  I can even create multiple subtypes, coercions and attributes by wrapping the whole lot in a for loop.  This is very useful for creating multiple attributes with similar properties.

In the example below, I have set up delegation using `handles`, so that `$person->get_first_name` is translated to `$person->first_name->value`.  Adding a writer gives provides an equivalent setter, making the interface to the class quite clean:

```
package MyApp::Type::Field;

use Moose;

has 'value'     => (
    is          => 'rw',
);

has 'size'      => (
    is          => 'ro',
    isa         => 'Int',
    writer      => '_set_size',
);

has 'required'  => (
    is          => 'ro',
    isa         => 'Bool',
    writer      => '_set_required',
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

package MyApp::Person;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
use namespace::autoclean;

{
    my $attrs = {
        title      => { size =>  5, required => 0 },
        first_name => { size => 45, required => 1 },
        last_name  => { size => 45, required => 1 },
    };

    foreach my $attr ( keys %{$attrs} ) {

        my $subtype = 'MyApp::Person::' . ucfirst $attr;

        subtype $subtype => as 'MyApp::Type::Field';

        coerce $subtype
           => from 'Str'
               => via { MyApp::Type::Field->new(
                   value    => $_,
                   size     => $attrs->{$attr}{'size'},
                   required => $attrs->{$attr}{'required'},
               ) };

        has $attr   => (
            is      => 'rw',
            isa     => $subtype,
            coerce  => 1,
            writer  => "set_$attr",
            handles => { "get_$attr" => 'value' },
            default => sub {
                MyApp::Type::Field->new(
                    size     => $attrs->{$attr}{'size'},
                    required => $attrs->{$attr}{'required'},
                )
            },
        );
    }
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

package MyApp::Test;

sub print_person {
    my $person = shift;

    printf "Title:      %s [%d][%d]\n" .
           "First name: %s [%d][%d]\n" .
           "Last name:  %s [%d][%d]\n",
           $person->title->value || '[undef]',
           $person->title->size,
           $person->title->required,
           $person->get_first_name || '[undef]',
           $person->first_name->size,
           $person->first_name->required,
           $person->get_last_name || '[undef]',
           $person->last_name->size,
           $person->last_name->required;
}

my $person;

$person = MyApp::Person->new(
    title      => 'Mr',
    first_name => 'Joe',
    last_name  => 'Bloggs',
);

print_person( $person );

$person = MyApp::Person->new();
$person->set_first_name( 'Joe' );
$person->set_last_name( 'Bloggs' );

print_person( $person );

1;
```

Prints:

```
Title:      Mr [5][0]
First name: Joe [45][6]
Last name:  Bloggs [45][7]
Title:      [undef] [5][0]
First name: Joe [45][8]
Last name:  Bloggs [45][9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is every person going to have different requirements for the `name` field?  This seems unlikely.

It seems more likely that you have a set of parameters for each `Field` accross the application. So define a type PersonName as a subtype of Field.  Your coercion would be from string to PersonName.  Then the coercion code and can apply the appropriate values to required and length when it calls `Field->new()`.

Also, this really seems like you are building an attribute object for a Moose object, which is based on a meta-object system that already provides attribute objects.  Why not extend your attribute object rather than make your own?

See the [Moose Cookbook Meta Recipes](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Meta/Recipe2.pod) for more info on this approach.

Comment: The Field is more like a MooseX::Types::Structured than an attribute with meta-attributes.  One example of use is a web form where each field needs a value, a max length (size) and a required flag.  The model (the Person class, in this example), sets the size and required flag.  `Field`, therefore is meant to be fairly generic, whilst the `Person` class is more specific.  I looked at meta-attributes before, but they are a bit awkward to access (`$person->meta->get_attribute('name')->size()`), for example.  A subtype may be an option.  I'll look into this...

Comment: I've just experimented with creating a subtype, and think it might provide a nice solution.  I'll do some more testing tomorrow...  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a proposed solution which uses your subtype suggestion. Thanks for your advice.